# Insert HTML element two (or more) times using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I insert a HTML element twice using JavaScript?

This code isn't working:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = 'Hello!';
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/9z82D/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok I found that you just have to use cloneNode:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = 'Hello!';
document.body.appendChild(div);
var div2 = div.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(div2);
```

Answer (score 10):

To elaborate on your answer, appendChild is not making a *copy* of your element 'div' and appending it to the end of the body, it's moving the actual node.

So if you have two elements, div and div2, and you do:

```
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.body.appendChild(div2);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

div gets inserted to the end of the body, then div2, then div gets moved from the top to the bottom. (see http://jsfiddle.net/9z82D/3/ )

This is helpful, because any changes you make to div after you append it after still reflected in the object div.  If this wasn't the case, you'd have to do an additional getElementsByTagName to recapture the element before making any other changes.

For example, try `div.innerText='goodbye';` after you've appended the node-- the text will update without having to append again.

Comment: Nice clarification. This behaviour is far from obvious, it's quite surprisning that a func named 'appendChild' also has the power to remove the child from it's previous location.
Most of us wouldn't think appending a node multiple times would be any different from, say, pushing an object to an array multiple times. But nodes are obviously quite special in js.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of cloning and creating multiple variables, you could just loop it:

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = 'Hello!';
  document.body.appendChild(div);  
}
```