# Iterating through HTMLcollection, only last elements gets applied change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to iterate through a HTMLcollection and append a child on each of them. But the change gets only applied to the last element,

```
div = table.getElementsByClassName("sectionExpandColumn");
var button = document.createElement("a");
button.setAttribute("class", "sectionExpand.collapsibleCriteria");
button.innerHTML = "Discussion";

for (var i=0; i<div.length; i++){
div[i].appendChild(button);
}
```

So, if there were 10 elements with classname "sectionExpandColumn" then only the 10th element gets the button.
I mean, I'm not very familiar with javascript and the code looks okay to me... What could be the problem?

Comment: Make copies: `div[i].appendChild(button.cloneNode());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML element two (or more) times using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244985/insert-html-element-two-or-more-times-using-javascript)